# How to make a method available in the whole project

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

I have the following code to handle a swipe gesture.

```
    func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    if (sender.direction == .Right) {
        print("Swipe Right")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("eventsModally", sender: self)
    }
}
```

What is the best practise to make this method available in the whole project, instead of implementing it in every ViewController class?

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put it in a [class extension.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID470)

```
extension UIViewController {
    func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        if (sender.direction == .Right) {
            print("Swipe Right")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("eventsModally", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: works perfect. is there an alternative way, that allowes me to use it in every controller, even if not every cotroller is UIViewController? f.e. UITableViewController?

Comment: `UITableViewController` _is a_ `UIViewController`, so this extension on `UIViewController` should work on any class - including `UITableViewController` - that inherits from `UIViewController`.

Comment: Ok didn't knew that. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: could you please edit your answer and tell me how to make the segue "eventsModally" generic?

Comment: I call the function with: `let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))` and I don't know how to give it a string as segue name.